# Laravel 5, how to run a specific method according to the URL received

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

In my routes files I have a bunch or routes for testing purposes:

```
/** testing controllers */
Route::get('viewemail', 'TestController@viewemail');
Route::get('restore', 'TestController@restore');
Route::get('sendemail', 'TestController@send_email');
Route::get('socket', 'TestController@socket');
Route::get('colors', 'TestController@colors');
Route::get('view', 'TestController@view_test');
Route::get('numbers', 'TestController@numbers');
Route::get('ncf', 'TestController@ncf');
Route::get('dates', 'TestController@dates');
Route::get('print', 'TestController@printer');
Route::get('{variable}', 'TestController@execute');
/** End of testing controllers */
```

I want to eliminate all those routes and simple use the name of the given URL to call and return the method:

I have accomplished that in this way:

```
Route::get('{variable}', 'TestController@execute');
```

And in my testing controller:

```
public function execute($method){
    return $this->$method();
}
```

Basically what I want to know if Laravel has a built in solution to do this, I was reading the documentation but couldn't find any way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From official documentation:**
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#implicit-controllers

> Laravel allows you to easily define a single route to handle every
>   action in a controller class. First, define the route using the
>   `Route::controller` method. The controller method accepts two
>   arguments. The first is the base URI the controller handles, while the
>   second is the class name of the controller:
>
> ```
> Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
> ```
>
> Next, just add methods to your controller. The method names should begin with the
>   HTTP verb they respond to followed by the title case version of the
>   URI:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace App\Http\Controllers;
>
> class UserController extends Controller
> {
>     /**
>      * Responds to requests to GET /users
>      */
>     public function getIndex()
>     {
>         //
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Responds to requests to GET /users/show/1
>      */
>     public function getShow($id)
>     {
>         //
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Responds to requests to GET /users/admin-profile
>      */
>     public function getAdminProfile()
>     {
>         //
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Responds to requests to POST /users/profile
>      */
>     public function postProfile()
>     {
>         //
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> As you can see in the example above, index methods will respond to the
>   root URI handled by the controller, which, in this case, is users.

Comment: I was reading the Routes docs not the Controllers docs, they should have a reference there, also I prefer my way of doing it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a route pattern for the endpoints you want to listen for. Route them to a controller action, and then inspect the request:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function handle(Request $request)
    {
        $method = $request->segment(1); // Gets first segment of URI

        // Do something…
    }
}
```

And in your route service provider:

```
$router->pattern('{variable}', 'foo|bar|qux|baz');
```